# DisconnectedContext was detected error detected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've added this code:

```
if (arrSettimgs[0] == "1")
{
   if ((webBrowserMain.Document != null) && (webBrowserMain.Document.Domain != domain))
   {
      webBrowserMain.Navigate(blockPage);
   }
}
```

The execution get stuck and eventually I get the following error:

```
DisconnectedContext was detected Message: Transition into COM context
0x2e07e2b0 for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following
error: System call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100
(RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)). This is typically because the COM context
0x2e07e2b0 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been
disconnected or it is busy doing something else. Releasing the
interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0x2e07e188). This
may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please
ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are
available for context transition, until the application is completely
done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components
that live inside them.
```

I searched the forum and came across answers that suggested to uncheck some properties, which I did, but it didn't work.

Comment: Samuel, welcome to Stackoverflow. Good formatting is your friend. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: The Question needs some more details about what `webBrowserMain` is and are you tying to here.